# attribute maxlength of input field is changing, but input doesn't care

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, attr

I have a function to limit the number of characters that a user can type into an input field for my game. It works, except that if it goes down by 1 or more in length, the user can still enter 1 or more characters than they should be able to.

I check the inspector, and it even shows maxlength changing correctly. However, for whatever reason, it still lets the user enter in a length equal to the max number of characters that the variable was equal to during the same session. Is it a bug? Any way to get it working correctly?

```
my_var = 150000; //this var changes often, can go down to 0 or up to 1000000000

function limitNumberOfCharacters() {
    x = my_var.toString().length;
    $('.my_input_class').attr('maxlength', x);
}

limitNumberOfCharacters(); //this gets called often
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/mDw6f/

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f2s4c/1/

Comment: Why are you coverting it to string and checking the length of the string? Why not this `x = my_var;` or this `$('.my_input_class').attr('maxlength', my_var);`

Comment: @codehorse Arun is correct, your code is working.  Look here http://jsfiddle.net/DaLk7/

Comment: No dude i dont think that may be the case. Your code is absolutely woring fine. Here is the fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/qfNLq/5/

Comment: @codehorse what if your number is in a format like `1, 2, 3` the length of your string is `1` always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDITTTT:

You are using `x` as a **global variable** and is probably getting changed from something else in your code.  Use `var x = my_var.toString().length;` (emphasis on `var`)

Honestly after seeing this code I was afraid there would be many more underlying problems but all I did was add `var` before the `xyz` and it works just as you want it to.

*Also fixed the issue of the previous bet amount returning to the input field.  It now results to a blank field.*

Cheers

### [Real Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m3YE7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this fiddle:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfNLq/5/)

Use the html input like I did in the code, no need to specify the maxlength attribute to it.

```
<input type="text" class="my_input_class"/>
```

and the script

```
my_var = 25; //this var changes often, can go down to 0 or up to 1000000000

function limitNumberOfCharacters() {
    x = my_var.toString().length;
    $('.my_input_class').attr('maxlength', x);
}

limitNumberOfCharacters();
```